# url context changing between local server and tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Hi I'm working on a application that has a weird problem. The application works fine in both local tomcat and remote tomcat deployments, but on certain modules the url context changes.

Here's one of the examples:

first I have this in my `Web.xml` as to eliminate doubt:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have the following form:

```
    <form name="cra" th:action="@{'/customer/relations/add/'}" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="craAcctCustNbr"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="craChildAcctCustNbr"/>
    </form>
```

which is called by javascript. Notice I'm using Thymeleaf tags. Usually this fixes the url so it is within the application's context.

Now in my local instance this translates to `localhost:8080/customer/relations/add` which goes to my spring mvc controller just fine. However in the remote tomcat deployment where the application is under context `testapp` it should translate to `XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/testapp/customer/relations/add`. This is not the case, it insteads does this: `XX.XX.XXX.XX:8080/customer/relations/add`, which then yields a 404 with message `The requested resource (/customer/account-relations/add/) is not available.`. The rest of the application works fine on the remote deployment server and stays within context.

Upon inspection, when I open the page and examine the source it is defined correctly as:

```
    <form name="cra" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/testapp/customer/relations/add/">
        <input type="hidden" name="craAcctCustNbr" />
        <input type="hidden" name="craChildAcctCustNbr" />
    </form>
```

However when the action occurs it goes into what I just explained.

I have no way to check the application log, and I am unsure if this is a tomcat issue, a spring security issue or a thymeleaf issue.

Any clues as to how I may solve this? Otherwise I would have to hold out on getting access to the remote logs and that would take me a bit of time to get the credentials to access them.

Comment: As step one, use Firebug or something to check the outgoing request URL. If it has the correct context in it, you'll know to look on the server side. If not, then client side. It may also show a redirect to the incorrect URL, which could give additional hints.

Comment: Did you try to set the th:action to th:action="@{'/testapp/customer/relations/add/'}" to see if it works or not ? I know this isn't the proper way to do it, but try give it a shot.

Comment: Ok this is weird, but apparently my app is working just fine now. I did nothing to fix it. It's odd. I just left it as is on the weekend. Perhaps a server problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was server-side. Apparently there were some caches that weren't being flushed, so the changes to my html/thymeleaf did not get through. Note that this can also be an unclean code issue, as well as perhaps local browser caches.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the page containing the form is already reached, you can simply use the "core" taglib to resolve the form's context:

```
<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"> ...
```

And...

```
<c:url value="/customer/relations/add/" var="customerUrl" />
<form name="cra" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="${customerUrl}">
```

Comment: I'm using thymeleaf. See my my comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to access a url or post data to a url use

```
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/customer/..."
```

or you need to include JSTL code

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and use c:url tag to specify URLS like

```
<c:url value="/customer/relations/add/"/>
```

Comment: This is not needed with thymeleaf. Remember I'm not using a traditional view resolver for JSPs. The problem was something else.